# Is it good practice to use static singleton to share UserData across whole application on Android?

Tags: android

So I have an entity that represents user, his profile and all of settings. Right now I am passing that as construction argument to every fragment that makes use of it. However, If application will be stopped for some reason, and passed data will be serialized/deserialized in bundle, every fragment will end up with a self contained copy of orignal entity, so any modification to it will not take affect in other fragments.

I want to use static singleton container for that. Is it a good way to resolve unwanted cloning on data structure that supposed to be a logic singleton accross whole application, or there is another way?

Comment: You could store user information in shared preferences.

Comment: dagger2 is good to use user data in application scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a wise idea to store a list of user details in shared preferences. Make a list and add all user data in it. Convert it into a string and add it into shared preferences.

Comment: Why not singleton?

Comment: because a singleton's instance will be destroyed on closing application. you will have to create new instance everytime you open the application.

Comment: And that is perfectlty fine as I have to (auto)log in anyway. If my app gets destroyed, it will start from entry point, in my case BootstrapActivity, where I am logging/registering user and proceeding to main activity

Answer (score 0):

Storing user data in shared preference are done most of us to keep user data. It might work but technically, its a bad practice.

You should use [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). Its an advanced topic but once you get the concept, you understand its advantages. One of them is ofcourse, [remembering your user.](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html)

Singleton might be another choice if you dont want to go for account manager.
You might have some issues with updates, you need to write your own update mechanism which can lead memory leaks. Update Listener references holded by singleton object can avoid other references being garbage collected. So once your done with update listener reference you need to nullify it.

Answer (score 0):

I **do not recommend** using Singleton for this. You can have problems of concurrency, or consistency. What would happen if the app is closed and then restarted? Or the context is switched and then restored?

For these reasons, and if you don't want to complicate a lot, use **shared preferences** for this.